# Simple 2D Perlin Noise in Python

Tags: python-3.x, perlin-noise, noise-generator

There is lots of different implementations of 2D perlin noise in Python.
My question is there a simple implementation of perlin noise in Python that fits in 1 function or 1 class? Or maybe there is easier-to-implement 2D noise that is similar to perlin noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be integers, or is double floating point precision good enough? Can you use Cython? There is a Cython wrapper for FastNoiseLite here: https://github.com/tizilogic/PyFastNoiseLite . You can convert the integers to doubles, with plenty of precision left over.

I would also suggest using the OpenSimplex2 or OpenSimplex2S noise option, rather than Perlin. Perlin as a base noise is very grid-aligned looking. Simplex/OpenSimplex2(S) directly address that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest implementation of Perlin noise I have found has been this.

https://pypi.org/project/perlin-noise/

Once installed, and initialised at the top of your code, simply calling the function `noise(float)` returns the value at that point of the noise field. Additionally, with "unlimited coordinate space", you can simply add more values to the noise function `noise(float,float)` to change to a 2D, 3D, or higher dimensional noise field.

They provide a couple of basic examples on the website which I found very helpful and sufficient to then be able to implement the library.